# Post Request going to Pending state

Tags: javascript, angularjs-http

I am using AngularJS and calling a REST using http. Below is my AJAX code, but all of my request are going to pending status in browser. I have searched this issue on internet and tried a lot of options but it is not working.

```
$http({
    method: "POST",
    url: './rest/sales/OrderPlacement',
    data : $.param({
        'j_username' : j_username,
        'j_password' : j_password                       
    }),
    headers : {
        'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }

})
.success(function(data,status) {
    console.log("Success occured");
    $scope.searched_products = data;
    $scope.myAccountName=j_username;
    console.log(data);
    $location.path("/checkout");
}, 
function(response) { // optional
    $scope.error = error;
    $location.path("/Login");
});
```

[image]

I am using spring security to interrupt my REST calls and validate the authentication and whole application is deployed on JBoss EAP 6.4. I do not see anything in the server/Spring logs as request is not reaching the server. Please suggest as I am stuck.

Comment: Have you figured it out why this was happened? Because i am also having the same problem with AngularJS and Spring MVC.

Comment: same issue here

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with my Angular fullstack application (MEAN app). In my case, the chrome showed exactly the same warning and the request state was pending for a while until the timeout occurs. At this point, I can see a log in server-side about the timeout. That gave me a clue that the request was actually reaching the backend, and however it is stuck somewhere in authentication code. Hence, the UI never got a response from the backend.

Then, I added some logs in my back-end code and found that my authentication implementation did not respond properly on a particular error case. Especially when the password was wrong. So, proper error handling helped me to solve this issue. It is still weird why chrome acted as if it was blocking the request (provisional headers shown warning)